# Newbie C Programmer Curious about Errors

Tags: c, function, variables, pointers, compiler-construction

Hey I'm a newbie programmer in C and do not understand these errors I'm getting in my program.  Can someone please explain to me what is wrong with my code and the way to go about fixing it. I am eager to learn this. Appreciate any help.

Compiler Message:

```
gcc project1shell.c
project1shell.c: In function ‘main’:
project1shell.c:55:8: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘hello’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
project1shell.c:16:6: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘char’
project1shell.c:62:8: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘forkk’ makes pointer from integer     without a cast [enabled by default]
project1shell.c:18:6: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘char’
```

My Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define CHILD 0
#define SIZE 256

char hello(char command[SIZE]);
void forkk(char command[SIZE]);
void exitt(char command[SIZE]);

/////////////////////////////

int main(void) {

/* variable delcarations */
char command[SIZE]="";
char buffer[SIZE]="";

/////////////////////////////

    /**** prompt the user with the program ****/
    printf("*** Welcome to LJ's Shell! ***\n\n");

    /**** implements exit and commands ****/
    while(1) {
       if (strcmp(command, "exit") == 0) {
          break;
       }
       hello(command[SIZE]);

       //prompt(command[SIZE], buffer[SIZE]);
       printf("nshell:~$ ");
       fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
       sscanf(buffer, "%s", command);

       forkk(command[SIZE]);
    }

}


///////// Functions //////////

/************ fork process **************/
void forkk(char command[SIZE]) {
    int pid = 0;
    int childvalue = 0;

    if (strcmp(command, "fork") == 0) {

       pid = fork();

       if (pid != CHILD) {   /* this is the parent */
           printf("I am the parent.  Ready to wait on the child.\n");
           pid = waitpid(-1, &childvalue, 0);
           printf("Child %d returned a value of %x in hex.\n", pid, childvalue);
           return;
       }
       else {  /* this is the child */
           printf("I am the child.\n");
           exit(2);
       }
    }
}

/***************** exit *******************/

void exitt(char command[SIZE]) {
    if (strcmp(command, "exit") == 0) {
       exit(0);
    }
}

/************* Hello Test ****************/
char hello(char command[SIZE]) {
    if (strcmp(command, "hello") == 0) {
    printf("Hello there!\n");
    //reset command back to ""
    }
}
```

Comment: You know, not everyone is going to be a top-notch programmer on the get go.  Why is Stackoverflow so hostile to newbie programmers?

Why is it so hard to answer a simple question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
hello(command[SIZE]);
```

to

```
hello(command);
```

the same applies to `forkk(command[SIZE]);`. This should solve the compile problem.

The problem is, `command` is an array, while `command[n]` is an element. And it's illegal to access `command[SIZE]` because the array has only SIZE - 1 elements.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably revisit the array syntax.

What you do when you call `hello(command[SIZE])` is to take the character *just after* your command array (the last valid index is `SIZE - 1`), and pass it to the hello function, which requires this char value (a signed integer) to be converted to a pointer.

The compiler finds that fishy, and issues a warning.

I am not quite sure why you `sscanf()` the buffer you just got from `fgets()`, you could just as easily `fscanf("%256s")` stdin